# Error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds excel java Apache poi

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I changed all data type in mapping but I dont know where the part of the code is error this:

> Error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible
>   bounds equality constraints: Map
>       lower bounds: Map   where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in method toList()

-- This my code --

```
public List<Map<String, String>> upload(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("");

        File tempFile = tempDir.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()).toFile();

        file.transferTo(tempFile);

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowStreamSupplier = uploadUtils.getRowStreamSupplier(sheet);

        Row headerRow = rowStreamSupplier.get().findFirst().get();

        List<String> headerCells = uploadUtils.getStream(headerRow)
                .map(Cell::getStringCellValue) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        int colCount = headerCells.size();

        return rowStreamSupplier.get()
                .skip(1)
                .map(row -> {

                    Map<CellType, List<Cell>> cellListMap = uploadUtils.getStream(row)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cell::getCellTypeEnum));

                    List<Object> cellList = Stream.of(
                    cellListMap.get(CellType.NUMERIC).stream().map(Cell::getNumericCellValue),
                    cellListMap.get(CellType.STRING).stream().map(Cell::getStringCellValue)
                    ).collect(Collectors.toList());     

                    return uploadUtils.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
                             .get()
                             .collect(toMap(headerCells::get, cellList::get));
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

-- UploadUtils.java --

```
public class UploadUtils {

    public Supplier<Stream<Row>> getRowStreamSupplier(Iterable<Row> rows) {
        return () -> getStream(rows);
    }

    public <T> Stream<T> getStream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
    }

    public Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cellIteratorSupplier(int end) {
        return () -> numberStream(end);
    }

    public Stream<Integer> numberStream(int end) {
        return IntStream.range(0, end).boxed();
    }

}
```

Comment: The `cellList::get` gets `Object`s. How shall those fit into a `Map<String, String>`? But this whole approach is misleading. Using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) will be the better approach. And because of the fact, that really empty cells are not stored in the `Excel` file and so `Iterator`s will not get them, the `java.util.stream.*` approach also needs to be rethink. Using `for` loops as shown in [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) might be better here.